# Python (Pyspark) nested list reduceByKey, Python list append to create nested list

Tags: python, list, pyspark, nested

I have an RDD input with the format as the following:

```
[('2002', ['cougar', 1]),
('2002', ['the', 10]),
('2002', ['network', 4]),
('2002', ['is', 1]),
('2002', ['database', 13])]
```

The '2002' is the key. So, I have key value pairs as:

```
 ('year', ['word', count])
```

Count is integer number, I would like to use reduceByKey to get the following result:

```
[('2002, [['cougar', 1], ['the', 10], ['network', 4], ['is', 1], ['database', 13]]')]
```

I struggle a lot to get a nest list as above. 
The main issue is the get the nested list. 
E.g. I have three list a, b and c

```
a = ['cougar', 1]
b = ['the', 10]
c = ['network', 4]

a.append(b)
```

will return a as

```
 ['cougar', 1, ['the', 10]]
```

and

```
x = []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
```

will return x as

```
  [['cougar', 1], ['the', 10]]
```

However, if then

```
  c.append(x)
```

will return c as

```
  ['network', 4, [['cougar', 1], ['the', 10]]]
```

All the above operation does not get me the desired result.

I want to get

```
   [('2002', [[word1, c1],[word2, c2], [word3, c3], ...]), 
   ('2003'[[w1, count1],[w2, count2], [w3, count3], ...])]
```

i.e the nested list should be:

```
  [a, b, c]
```

Where a, b, c themselves are list with two elements.

I hope the question is clear and any advice?

Comment: Why do you have to use ReduceByKey instead of a simple **rdd_nested = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list)** (command that give you exactly what you want)?

Comment: @titiro89,  That is amazing, I am new to pyspark, thanks for the answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: @ Yu Xiang, perfect! I posted an answer so you can mark it as accepted if you deem it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use ReduceByKey for this problem.

- Define RDD

`rdd = sc.parallelize([('2002', ['cougar', 1]),('2002', ['the', 10]),('2002', ['network', 4]),('2002', ['is', 1]),('2002', ['database', 13])])`

- See the RDD values with
  `rdd.collect()`:

`[('2002', ['cougar', 1]),  ('2002', ['the', 10]),  ('2002', ['network', 4]),  ('2002', ['is', 1]),  ('2002', ['database', 13])]`

- Apply the groupByKey function and map the values as list as you can see in the [Apache Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey).

`rdd_nested = rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list)`

- See the RDD grouped values
  `rdd_nested.collect()`:

`[('2002', [['cougar', 1], ['the', 10], ['network', 4], ['is', 1], ['database', 13]])]`

Answer (score 1):

I have come out one solution:

```
def wagg(a,b):  
    if type(a[0]) == list: 
        if type(b[0]) == list:
            a.extend(b)
        else: 
            a.append(b)
        w = a
    elif type(b[0]) == list: 
        if type(a[0]) == list:
            b.extend(a)
        else:    
            b.append(a)
        w = b
    else: 
        w = []
        w.append(a)
        w.append(b)
    return w  


rdd2 = rdd1.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: wagg(a,b))
```

Does anyone have better solution?